# Plotting the difference of two columns in the same file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file with 12 columns. I'd like to plot the data with x axis being my 1st column and y axis being the difference between the 2nd and the 8th columns.

I tried `plot "test.dat" using 1:(8-2)` but naturally, it is interpreted as `1:6`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `$`, just add them and they will allow you to reference the column contents

```
plot "test.dat" using 1:($8-$2) w linespoints
```

`$1` is a shortcut for `column(1)` and if the column numbers are stored in variables `i` and `j` you  *must* use the `column` statement to select the respective columns:

```
i = 8
j = 2
plot "test.dat" using 1:(column(i)-column(j)) w lp
```

Comment: That worked! But now, it fails when I pass the column number as an argument to the .gp script

Comment: Then you must use `plot 'test.dat' using 1:(column(i)-column(j)) w lp`.

Comment: @Christoph +1 for that, would you like to edit my answer and add it.

Comment: @cagirici I think your actual problem was solved by Christoph.

Comment: @Christoph Yeah, that's right. I did not see the edit was done by him. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

plot "< awk '{print $8 - $2}' test"

Comment: OK, but why using an external program like awk if you can do it in gnuplot?